# Why predicted values differ in knn regression when using caret vs FNN

Tags: r, regression, knn, caret

I was trying to do some manual calculations of knn regression and came across this unusual error.  The predicted values done by hand do not match with the ones I got from the 'knnreg' function in the 'caret' package.  So I used another package (FNN) as a second check and discovered that my manual calculations do agree with the ones from the FNN package.  So I'm really confused now.  Here is an example code:

```
# caret  vs. FNN packages
# issue in predictions

library(caret)
library(FNN)
library(dbscan)

n <- 100

x <- rnorm(n)
y <- 2 + 3*x + rnorm(n, sd = 0.5)

x <- as.matrix(x)

# using caret
knn_caret <- knnreg(x, y, k = 5)
yhat_caret <- predict(knn_caret, newdata = x)

# using FNN
knn_FNN <- knn.reg(train = x, y = y, k = 5)
yhat_FNN <- knn_FNN$pred

# manual calculation using the neighbors.
# choose a point
i <- 3
nn <- kNN(x, k = 5) #using the caret package
neighbors <- nn$id[i, ]

mean(y[neighbors]) # manual calculation

yhat_FNN[i]  # FNN package

yhat_caret[i] # caret package
```

If you can point to any mistake that I may have made in my code or any thoughts on this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What package is the `kNN` function from? It doesn't seem to be in `caret`

Comment: @rw2, Good catch!  Sorry, it was from `dbscan` package.